# Converting English statements into symbolic form and then negating them

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I want to convert these statements into symbolic form and then negate them:

> *(a) For all integers x there is an integer y that is smaller than x.*
>
> *(b) Every integer greater than 4 is odd.*
>
> *(c) There is an integer less than 10 that belongs to all elements of P(Z).*

This I what I think the symbolic forms are:

*(a) $∀x ∈ Z, ∃y ∈ Z, y < x$*

*(b) $∀x ∈ Z, x > 4, odd(x)$*

*(c) $∃x ∈ Z, x < 10, x ∈ P(Z)$*

With the negations:

*(a) $∃x ∈ Z, ∀y ∈ Z, y≥x$*

*(b) $∃x ∈ Z, x ≤ 4, even(x)$*

*(c) $∀x ∈ Z, x ≥ 10, x ∉ P(Z)$*

(b) and (c) are particularly confusing me and I think I have made a mistake in either/both the symbolic form or negation. Did I do these correctly and if not can someone explain where I went wrong?

Comment: For (b) you need "if..., then..." ($\to$).

Comment: (c) needs "and ($\land$) and you have to say that $x$  belongs to all elements of P(Z) and not to P(Z)

Comment: So is (b) $∀x∈Z,x>4→odd(x)$ and (c) $∃x∈Z∧x<10,x∈P(Z)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b) should be $\forall x \in Z , x > 4 \to Odd(x)$

Sentence c) is actually ambiguous, and can be interpreted in two different ways:

One interpretation  is to say that there is a specific number smaller that 10 that is an element of all the elements of $P(Z)$. That is: it is the same number every time for all those elements.  This would be symbolized as:

$\exists x \in Z , \forall y \in P(Z), x < 10 \land x \in y$

So, this claim would be true if, for example, we find the number $6$ to be an element of every element of $P(Z)$.... which is the same as saying that $6$ would be an element of every subset of $Z$ ... which is clearly not true.

A different interpretation is to say that all elements of $P(Z)$ have their own number smaller than $10$ that's in the set, but it need not be the same number for all elements.

This would be symbolized as:

$\forall y \in P(Z), \exists x \in Z ,  x < 10 \land x \in y$

Note that also this claim is a false claim: the set containing of all numbers greater than $10$, for example, is a subset of $Z$, and hence an element of $P(Z)$, but it has no number than smaller than $10$ in it. Nor does the empty set.

So .. which on is meant?  Well, we just don't know. That's the difference between English and logic: English is ambiguous, but in logic we don't have such ambiguities.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a little confused about (c). I feel like I want to say $∃x∈Z,∀x∈P(Z),x<10$. Why is this statement not the same as the worded version? Can you explain (c) a little more?

Comment: @AMM  Aaaaah .... so this is interesting. I had not realized that before, but now that you say it, this sentence is actually ambiguous.  One interpretation (mine) is to say that there is a specific number smaller that 10 that is an element of all the elements of $P(Z)$. That is: it is the same number every time for all those elements.  Your interpretation is to to say that all elements of $P(Z)$ have their own number smaller than $10$ that's in the set, but it need not be the same number.  Let me edit my Answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That makes a lot more sense. Also, for the negation of (c) if I was using the first interpretation, I said it would be $∀x∈Z, ∃y∈P(Z), x≥10 ∨ x∉y$. I was having a hard time trying to figure out what the worded version of that would be. Could I say "for all integers, they are either greater than or equal to 10 or do not belong to an element of P(Z)"?

Comment: @AMM 
That statement is equivalent to $\forall x \in Z , \exists  y \in P(Z), x < 10 \to \neg x \in y$ .. which is itself equivalent to $\forall x \in Z , x < 10 \to \exists  y \in P(Z) \neg x \in y$. So: for all numbers smaller than $10$ there is some element of the powerset of $Z$ that the number does not belong to.